# Can I enter the UK the night before my visa start date?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have been granted a UK visitor visa which I applied for in Dubai. My visa application states 24th June, but my visa start date states 25th June. I have my graduation ceremony to attend on 25th June so I want to travel on 24th June. What can I do about this, as the airline will not allow me board before 25th?

Comment: The time of boarding is not what counts. If the flight you're trying to board is scheduled to _arrive_ before the visa is valid, expect that the airline will refuse you.

Comment: I did a small edit to remove the caps, as it's considered shouting and not very nice (and capitalized others, the 'I' when it refers you).

Comment: You can either request a new visa or [book a flight arriving in the UK in the early AM](https://www.google.com/flights/#flt=/m/01f08r./m/04jpl.2018-06-25.DXBLHR0BI97;c:USD;e:1;s:0;sd:1;t:f;tt:o;sp:.USD.52814)

Comment: Thanks! I have checked with some airlines but they said I cant even travel with 12.40am flight on 25th as I will have to board 1hr before my flight

Comment: It’s not the boarding that matters. It’s the time where you will request entry to the U.K. which matters. One airline might be rigid but it should work mostly.

Comment: Note, however, that the rules matter less than the airline's interpretation of the rules, since they are the ones letting you on or not.

Comment: Have you considered transiting to circumvent this problem? Any Schengen airport *should* let you transit, and some airports like Frankfurt (as far as I'm aware) allow visa free international transit. You could fly to Frankfurt on the 24th then fly onward to the UK on the first flight on the 25th.

Answer (score 2):

If your visa says 25 then 25 it is. You can not reach there on 24th and claim that I applied for 24th, even the airline will refuse boarding. Try to rebook so you reach in the early hours of 25th.

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure i will be allowed to board even if the flight gets to UK on the early hours of 25th? I can actually do that.

Comment: Yes you will be because you will reach the U.K. within the validity of your visa. But it might take some convincing so I would talk to the airline while getting the ticket and confirm.